# Is there a difference between creating a view object explicitly in the scope of the class vs the loadView function?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

I was following a tutorial from a book and want to move ahead without reading the code in the book to see what I would come up with on my own based on the instructions.  My code is a little different by creating the MKMapView object globally outside of the loadView() function however the book creates the MKMapView object inside the loadView() function.  Both processes work so I want to know if there is much of a difference or preference among the iOS development community?

Thank you in advance.

My code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    var mapView: MKMapView = MKMapView()

    override func loadView() {
        view = mapView
    }

}
```

The book's code:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController {

    var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func loadView() {
        mapView = MKMapView()
        view = mapView
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is in the first case the map view is created right when the view controller is initialized.

In the second case, the view is lazily created when the `viewController.view` is first accessed.

I'd recommend the second approach since that's in line with Apple's recommendation.